# Firebase Push Notifications to Authenticated Users

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently in the app

- user logs in.
- user subscribes/unsubscribes to/from some topics.

*Case 1:*

- user closes app without logging out

*Case 2:*

- user logs out and closes the app

In both cases the user receives notifications as and when its published by the server.

I intend that only logged in users receive notifications. I know I can acheive it by keeping track of topics a user has subscribed to, and then unsubscribe them when they log out. Is there any other way to acheive this functionality?

Comment: Have you figure out?

Comment: @SagarChavada I just unsubscribed the user from the topics when they logged out, and re-subscribed when they logged in again

Comment: Thanks man.. Thats good solution